# MediaStream livestream conversion to HLS using fluent ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, fluent-ffmpeg, mediastream

I'm trying to build server that converts Browser MediaStream to HLS video streaming using `fluent-ffmpeg`. (MediaStream -> Socket.IO -> Server -> ffmpeg -> HLS).

server-code:

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const id = v4();
    const StreamFolder = path.join(__dirname,`/stream/${id}/`);
    const InputPath = path.join(StreamFolder, 'stream.webm');
    const filePath = path.join(StreamFolder, 'stream.m3u8');

    let writeStream: null | NodeJS.WritableStream = null;
    let readStream: null | NodeJS.ReadableStream = null;
    let ffmpegCommand: null | FfmpegCommand = null;

    CreateStreamFolder(StreamFolder);
    writeStream = createWriteStream(InputPath, { flags: 'a' });
    socket.on('stream-data', async (data:ArrayBuffer) => {
        const bufferData = Buffer.from(data);
        if(!writeStream) return;
        if(!readStream) 
            readStream = createReadStream(InputPath, { flags: 'r' });
        writeStream.write(bufferData);
        if(!ffmpegCommand) {
            ffmpegCommand =  Ffmpeg(InputPath)
            .inputFormat('webm')
            .output(filePath)
            .outputOptions(['-hls_time 10', '-hls_list_size 6', '-hls_flags delete_segments', '-hls_segment_filename stream%03d.ts'])
            .on('start', () => {
                console.log('HLS conversion started');
            })
            .on('error', (error: any) => {
                console.error('Error during HLS conversion:', error);
            });
            ffmpegCommand.run();
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        if(ffmpegCommand) ffmpegCommand.kill("SIGKILL");
        RemoveStreamFolder(path.join(__dirname,`/stream/${id}`));
    } );
});
```

client-code:

```js
const socket = io();
        function startStream(){
            navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true,audio:true}).then(stream => {
                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async e => {
                    socket.emit('stream-data', await e.data.arrayBuffer());
                }

                mediaRecorder.start(10000);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
```

The **socket** itself **works** and sends the MediaStream to server.

Then the **ffmpeg** is converting and sometimes **crashes**(Invalid data found when processing input).

But the **ffmpeg** is **not** **creating** any `.m3u8` or `.ts` files.
The only file inside of stream folder is the `.webm` input file, so im not able to see the hls video.